# My uniqueness validation is not being run. What am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I created a pair of models: State and Country. They have several fields and one FK relationship:

```
+-------+      +---------+
| State +----<>+ Country +
+-------+N .. 1+---------+
```

Being `country` the `belongs_to` association (`country_id` the column).

Both Country and State have an internal code, and State has a uniqueness constraint on `(code, country)`.

When I run these commands in console:

```
us = Country.find_by_iso_abbr :US
ak = State.find_by iso_abbr: :AK, country: us
State.create(iso_abbr: :ak, country: us, name: 'Foo')
```

These lines actually work as expected. The `iso_abbr` in both tables represent the actual code fields I talked about.

When executing, this code explodes as expected (`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`).

However I wanted to include a model validator so the database-level explosion is never reached via model. What I tried is:

> models/country.rb
>   *omitted code replaced with ellipsis since it is not relevant for this problem*

```
class Country < ...
    ...
    validates_uniqueness_of :iso_abbr
    ...
end
```

> models/state.rb
>   *omitted code replaced with ellipsis since it is not relevant for this problem*

```
class State < ...
    ...
    validates_uniqueness_of :iso_abbr, scope: :country
    ...
end
```

And when running again the 3 lines, I expect the `.create` sentence to return an invalid, unsaved object (since validation should fail) instead of exploding with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`, since that explosion makes me think that no validation is being executed (or perhaps the validation is passing!).

My Rails version is 4.2.0.

**Edit**: Confirmed! The validation is *passing*. From my viewpoint it should fail. By executing this in console: `State.new(iso_abbr: :ak, country: us, name: 'Foo').valid?` I get `true` as a result, while I expect `false`.

**Edit 2**: OTOH if I write `Country.create(iso_abbr: :US, name: 'Foo')` validation runs as expected (`iso_abbr` is unique by itself in `Country` model) and fails as expected (and not with exception).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a result of the difference in the two symbols used in the OP: `:ak` and `:AK` would not be seen the same by a DB such as Postgres due to it running case-sensitive comparisons.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. My question was not regarding the exception but regarding the validation *passing* instead of failing.

Comment: But the validation isn't passing ... it's failing due to the RecordNotUnique - the link/quote from above is from `validates_uniqueness_of` in the Rails API

Comment: No. If I try this in console `State.new(iso_abbr: 'ak', country: us, name: 'Cucaracha').valid?` the validation passes (i.e. returns `true`).

Comment: Is there a difference, then, in your DB between your two symbols: `:ak` and `:AK`. I use Postgres and it's case-sensitive so it would not see 'ak' and 'AK' as the same (basing that off your code in the OP where there is :AK and :ak)

Comment: I think you nailed it!

Comment: Edit it in the answer please :)

Comment: LOL .. will do ... sadly, that was what I was going to write first :)

Comment: Fact: my validation example was wrong since I should use :AK (uppercase) as when I retrieved the state. However the database is Case Insensitive for my columns.

Comment: Well, sorry for the mis-start but glad it's sorted!

Comment: :) Thanks and have a great rest of your week!